# How to apply catalog price rule on out of stock product?

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules, out-of-stock, magento-catalog

[image: https://i.imgur.com/VIPP7wA.png]

here we have created a custom catalog price rule for out of stock products, but it didn't apply. You can get reference using the below image. I want to display the product price as 50 rupees when product is out of stock.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/JlcGwOl.png]

Comment: Did you run indexing?